# Angular 2 routing inside a component not working (this.router.navigate not working)

Tags: javascript, angular, router

Im trying to develop an angular 2 app that routes to a different component once a specific condition is met, for this i used the this.router.navigate method but it doesnt seem to execute as it keeps showing the "Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined" error. will appreciate any help on this :)

The specific component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { RouterModule, Routes, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-searching',
  templateUrl: './searching.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./searching.component.css']
})
export class SearchingComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private router:Router) { }

ngOnInit() {
 var elem = document.getElementById("rightSideMovingProgressBar"); 
 var elem2 = document.getElementById("progressText");
 var height = 100;
 var height2 = 0;
 var id = setInterval(frame, 20);
 function frame() {
    if (height <= 0) {
        clearInterval(id);
        this.router.navigate(['/details']);
    } else {
        height--;
        height2++; 
        elem.style.height = height + 'vh';
        elem2.innerHTML = height2 + '%'; 
    }
  } 
}

}
```

The error

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `this` in the `frame` is no longer points to the component. Use the following:

```
 var id = setInterval(()=>{ frame() }, 20);
```

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44739585/2545680) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback/20279485#20279485) answers for more information and other possible approaches using `bind` and `bound class properties`.

Answer (score 1):

You can store `this` into a variable:

`var that = this`;

inside the function you can use as

`that.router.navigate(['/details']);`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much :), yours and Maximus answers did the trick :)