# Typescript passing variables in functions

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-services

new to Typescript and trying to get my head around it.

the following is the code that basically generates three random numbers and i use those to select random objects from json.

```
    @Injectable()
 export class TrackService {
     public drawn :number[]=[];

     constructor(private http: Http) {


     }
     public getRandomTrack(): Observable<Track[]> {
         this.generateRandomNumbers();
         console.log(this.drawn);  //this.drawn is available here 
         return this.http
         .get(API_ENDPOINT)
         .map(this.extractRandomData);
     }



     public extractRandomData(res: Response) {
         let body = res.json();        
         console.log(this.drawn); //undefined here

         var randomTrack = [];

         for(var i=0;i<this.drawn.length; i++){
             randomTrack.push(body.results[this.drawn[i]]);
         }

         return randomTrack;
     }


     private generateRandomNumbers(){
         var available = [];

         for (var i = 1; i<= 55; i++) {
             available.push(i);
         }

         for (var i = 0; i <3; i++) {
             var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * available.length));
             this.drawn.push(available[random]);
             available.splice(random, 1);
         }

         return this.drawn;
     }
```

as you see inside extractRandomData this.drawn is undefined, how do i pass the this.drawn into that function so i can access that array.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind the context:

```
 public getRandomTrack(): Observable<Track[]> {
     this.generateRandomNumbers();
     console.log(this.drawn);  //this.drawn is available here 
     return this.http
     .get(API_ENDPOINT)
     .map((v) => { this.extractRandomData(v) });
 }
```

See [“this” cannot be used in typescript function (Angular)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44739585/2545680)
 for more details.

Comment: Hi Maximus thanks! Excuse my ignorance, what is v here ?

Comment: it's just a variable that will hold a value

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by adding this at the end

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_array_map.htm

```
public getRandomTrack(): Observable<Track[]> {
         this.generateRandomNumbers();
         console.log(this.drawn);
         return this.http
         .get(API_ENDPOINT)
         .map(this.extractRandomData,this);
     }
```

thoughts on how good or bad is this?

Answer (score 1):

Drawn array is global in your service so you can access it whenever you want inside service, but your problem is in the map call, you should call like below:

```
return this.http.get(API_ENDPOINT)
            .map(responseData => this.extractRandomData(responseData));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the above answers. Both are right.
Refer this link for more info [this is undefined in map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148827/this-is-undefined-inside-map-function-reactjs)

Sample code

```
public getRandomTrack(){
  this.generateRandomNumbers();
  console.log(this.drawn);
  [1,2].map(this.extractData,this); //Pass this as argument
  [1,2].map(data => {               // Arrow function
  console.log(this.drawn);
}

 extractData(val : any){
  console.log(val);
  console.log(this.drawn);
 }
```