# How to read "this" inside promise response in Angular

Tags: angular

```
this.vendorService.getCities(e.id)
    .then((d) => {
            this.cityList = d.info;
        }

    });
```

when I check this.cityList in breakpoints it throw error but in console.log(this.cityList) it works fine .

I am using Angular-cli

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cityList' of undefined

Comment: Show your code where you call `this.vendorService.getCities`

Comment: ^ This. You lost `this` in parent function scope.

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44739585/2545680