# string interpolation does not work thru setInterval

Tags: angular

In this basic app.component.ts sample snippet (created only for learning purposes), I've observed that if I use a setInterval block in the constructor, string-interpolating a template variable from that block is not gonna work.

I know this is not a meaningful example but it does show the issue:
What technique should be used here so we can update {{ timeDisplay }} area in the template?

This looks like a scope issue. 
Can this be solved thru a global variable? Or what's a better way to tackle this capability?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  timeDisplay: string;

  constructor () {
    this.timeDisplay = 'time will be displayed right here.';

    // set timer
    setInterval(
        function(){
            this.timeDisplay = new Date(); // this does not create an error but does not do anything neither. it is most likely timeDisplay variable is not in the constructor's scope
        },
        1000
    );

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're losing context for `this` here since function expressions don't preserve context:

```
// set timer
setInterval(
    function(){
        this.timeDisplay = new Date(); // this does not create an error but does not do anything neither. it is most likely timeDisplay variable is not in the constructor's scope
        ^^^ - points to global object, not `AppComponent`
    },
    1000
);
```

change it to arrow functions that preserve the context:

```
// set timer
setInterval(
    () => {
        this.timeDisplay = new Date();
    },
    1000
);
```

For more information see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44739585/2545680).

Comment: you are right on. that's the answer I was looking for but I still do not get why your approach works so the `this` works there! Can you elaborate the working code a little bit more? ALL I CAN SEE THERE is that you are using an arrow function. Is that it?

Comment: @AverageJoe, I've added a bit more explanation. Yes, arrow function preserves context for `this` and it's that's required. The answer I linked will give you all the information you need to understand why it works

Comment: There is one more problem in the code; I happened to assign an object ( the date object that is ) onto a string. So as a result, we do not get a valid run time off of the current code. In Angular, is there a temporary type conversion on the fly like we do in PHP: ex: (int) '5'. what can we do to assign the string representation of the new Date response ( like it would show in an alert )? alert(new Date() ) works.

Comment: _So as a result, we do not get a valid run time off of the current code._ what do you get rendered in HTML?

Comment: The err was `Type 'Date' cannot be converted to type 'string'.`. TSC dies there, & it does not want to compile. I had this in the HTML but it does not go that far: {{ timeDisplay | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}

Comment: so change `timeDisplay: string;` to `timeDisplay: Date;`